# Sakai build error after following installation guide

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, sakai

I have setup my environment for Sakai 19.0 from source following the guide on [https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=109772882.](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=109772882)

However when I try to build the source as detailed in **4.0** of the guide I am getting an error. Below are the logs with debug switched on:

```sh
C:\Users\Chitova\Desktop\Projects\sakai\master>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/oss-parent/1/oss-parent-1.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.sakaiproject:master:19.0 (C:\Users\Chitova\Desktop\Projects\sakai\master\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.sakaiproject:oss-parent:pom:1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/oss-parent/1/oss-parent-1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
C:\Users\Chitova\Desktop\Projects\sakai\master>mvn clean install -X
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T19:29:23+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\Chitova\Desktop\Projects\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Users\Chitova\Desktop\Projects\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\Chitova\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\Chitova\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\Chitova\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/oss-parent/1/oss-parent-1.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\Chitova\.m2\repository\org\sakaiproject\oss-parent\1\oss-parent-1.pom.lastUpdated
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.sakaiproject:oss-parent:pom:1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/oss-parent/1/oss-parent-1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 11

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:416)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:672)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:663)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:253)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.sakaiproject:master:19.0 (C:\Users\Chitova\Desktop\Projects\sakai\master\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.sakaiproject:oss-parent:pom:1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/oss-parent/1/oss-parent-1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 11 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact org.sakaiproject:oss-parent:pom:1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/oss-parent/1/oss-parent-1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:244)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:899)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:751)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:463)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:432)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:396)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:672)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:663)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:253)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.sakaiproject:oss-parent:pom:1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/oss-parent/1/oss-parent-1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:191)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.sakaiproject:oss-parent:pom:1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/oss-parent/1/oss-parent-1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/oss-parent/1/oss-parent-1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1039)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:977)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
        ... 31 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
C:\Users\Chitova\Desktop\Projects\sakai\master>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On January 15, 2020 the Maven Central repository disabled access through HTTP (cf. [Sonatype blog](https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https)).

While recent version of Maven have the correct URL for Maven Central in their [Super POM](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html) older ones might still use the HTTP URL. Upgrade your Maven installation or check whether your didn't override the Maven Central repository in your `settings.xml` file.

The repository configuration should look like this:

```xml
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
```